# Fix Write protected usb drive windows xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have a pc where i have working on. The problem is where when i want to send some data to usb drive or i want to delete a file from that usb device, system will be show me "write protected" message. The account is admin type. And curent operating system is XP. This account is not primary account. And for some security reasons some limitations are performed. How can i fix this problem? Where is the problem?

Comment: Could you give more details and also format the question better?

Comment: To and from other USB devices you can read and write?

Comment: @yisroel tech in all type of usb drives i can read but cant write

Comment: You say "his account is not primary account". Have you tried if this is that way on the primary account too?

Comment: @yisroel tech i have not allowed to access that account. I have not user password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the fix from [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/the-disk-is-write-protected-windows):

1. Create a system restore point first ([here](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/create-a-restore-point-manually-in-xp/)'s how) and then press
   **Windows Key + R** combination, type put **regedit** in Run dialog box and
   hit Enter to open the Registry Editor.
2. In the left pane, navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`
3. In the left pane of this location, right click the **Control** registry key and select **New -> Key**. Name the new sub-key so created as **StorageDevicePolicies**. Now come to the right pane of this sub-key i.e. **StorageDevicePolicies**, right-click and select **New -> DWORD Value**. Name the newly created DWORD as **WriteProtect**. (In some cases, you might find that this DWORD under the subkey already exists and the DWORD has a Value set to **1**. Double-click on the DWORD to modify its Value data.)
4. In the above-shown box, change the Value data to **0** from **1**. Click OK.
   Close the Registry Editor, restart the computer and check if the
   issue is resolved.

Comment: Hi , I did it all still not working . I am using windows 10

Comment: What's your situation? You have an SD card or a USB flash drive?

Comment: I have Sandisk usb drive  , with no switch for readonly

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an external exFAT hard drive (the solution might or might not be specific to exFAT, just try it and see...)

First I tried the `diskpart` command line tool [as sketched in this scenario](https://www.easeus.com/storage-media-recovery/remove-write-protection-in-windows-10-8-7.html) (`list disk`, `select disk 2`, `attributes disk clear readonly`). Didn't work, the last command was apparently not accepted for some reason.

Second, I tried `chkdsk /f X:`, on a mounted drive, [as sketched here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/268781-45-disk-write-protected), and it worked!!! :-) No need for even re-mounting the drive! So the reason was there was something unclean on the exFAT partition so Win XP mounted it readonly, and the chkdsk cleared it and it suddenly was possible to write to that disk :-)